# Increasing rate of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

Consider $f: X \rightarrow X$ continuous, with $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ compact convex.

I am wondering on conditions on $f$ so that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that

$$ (x-y)^\top \left( f(x) - f(y) \right) \geq \epsilon \left( f(x) - f(y) \right)^\top \left( f(x) - f(y) \right) $$

for all $x,y \in X$.

For instance, $f$ constant is enough. Same if $f(x) := A x$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is diagonal with non-negative eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is a kind of *monotonicity* condition; specifically, such $f$ is called *inverse-strongly monotone*. The name is explained by the fact that the related condition
$$\langle x-y , g(x)-g(y)\rangle \ge \epsilon\,\|x-y\|^2 \tag{1} $$
is called *strong monotonicity*. Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to the left side of (1) we see  that  $g$ satisfies the inverse-Lipschitz condition $\|g(x)-g(y)\|\ge \epsilon\,\|x-y\|$; in particular it is injective. The inverse $f=g^{-1}$ satisfies the condition in your post; hence the name inverse-strongly monotone.

The name should not be taken literally since   an inverse-strongly monotone map need not be invertible (as examples in your post show).

An important example of inverse-strongly monotone map is nearest point projection onto a convex closed set; one can even take  $\epsilon=1$.  One can also produce such maps in the form $x-h(x)$ for suitably contracting $h$. For details, see

- [*Strong convergence theorems for nonexpansive mappings and inverse-strongly monotone mappings*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.na.2003.07.023) by Hideaki Iiduka and Wataru Takahashi

which gives references to other papers on the subject. Or just google the term.

One more example: if $u:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is a differentiable convex function with bounded gradient (i.e., Lipschitz), then the gradient map $f = \nabla u$  is inverse-strongly monotone. This can be inferred from classical results in convex analysis: the convex conjugate $u^*$ is *strongly convex*, hence $\nabla (u^*)$ is strongly monotone.